# Error Message "TFileListBox not found" opening an old delphi 6 program

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

We got this program for migration purposes. Still first we have to get it running / build a version using the old environment to check if this works.

How can we get this component? Which library is it in?
Google does not have any helping information.

I tried to build the application and expected it to work properly.

Comment: "Google does not have any helping information" [LMGTFY](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22TFileListBox%22+%22Delphi%22)

Comment: Try the IDE's *Search->Find in files* menu item. Point it toward the VCL source folders and tell it to include subdirectories. Important lesson to learn.

Answer (score 2):

The [`TFileListBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.TFileListBox) component is declared in the `FileCtrl` unit (aka `Vcl.FileCtrl` since Delphi XE2 - but [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names) didn't exist yet in Delphi 6).

On the Component Palette, it is located under the `"Win 3.1"` tab (along with the [`TDirectoryListBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.TDirectoryListBox), [`TDriveComboBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.TDriveComboBox), and [`TFilterComboBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.TFilterComboBox) components).